# Why am I getting a segmentation fault on a limit less than 169?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

The program below is supposed to count the words in a C file. If I define `MAXWORD` to be less than 169 I get a segmentation fault. I find this to be confusing as I never use more than 8 characters from that 'word' string I declare inside of main. Not sure where or what to look at next so any pointers (no pun intended) would be appreciated.

After I compile it with `gcc wc.c getword.c -o wc` I run `./wc < wc.c` I get a segmentation fault but only when I set `MAXWORD` less than 169.

**This is the wc.c file**

```
#include "getword.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXWORD 169

struct tnode {
    char *word;
    int count;
    struct tnode *left;
    struct tnode *right;
};

struct tnode *addtree(struct tnode *, char *);
void printtree(struct tnode *);

int main(void) {
    char word[MAXWORD];
    struct tnode *root;

    while (getword(word, MAXWORD) != EOF) {
        printf("word: %s\n", word);
        if (isalpha(word[0]))
            root = addtree(root, word);
    }
    printtree(root);

    return 0;
}

struct tnode *talloc(void);

struct tnode *addtree(struct tnode *p, char *word) {
    int cond;

    if (p == NULL) {
        p = talloc();
        p->word = strdup(word);
        p->count = 1;
        p->left = p->right = NULL;
    } else if ((cond = strcmp(word,  p->word)) == 0)
        p->count++;
    else if (cond < 0)
        p->left = addtree(p->left, word);
    else
        p->right = addtree(p->right, word);
    return p;
}

struct tnode *talloc(void) {
    return (struct tnode *) malloc(sizeof(struct tnode));
}

void printtree(struct tnode *p) {
    if (p != NULL) {
        printtree(p->left);
        printf("%4d %s\n", p->count, p->word);
        printtree(p->right);
    }
}
```

**And here's the getword.c file:**

```
#include "getword.h"

#define STACKMAX 100

void skip_quote(char c);
void skip_comment(char c);
void skip_line(void);

int getch(void);
void ungetch(int);

int getword(char *word, int lim) {
    int c;
    char *w = word;

    while (isspace(c = getch()))
        ;
    if (c != EOF)
        *w++ = c;
    if (c == '#') {
        skip_line();
        return c;
    }
    if (c == '"' || c == '\'') {
        skip_quote(c);
        return c;
    }
    if (c == '/' && ((c = getch()) == '*' || c == '/')) {
        skip_comment(c);
        return c;
    }

    if (!isalpha(c)) {
        *w = '\0';
        return c;
    }

    for ( ; --lim > 0; w++)
        if (!isalnum(*w = getch()) && *w != '_') {
            ungetch(*w);
            break;
        }
    *w = '\0';
    return word[0];
}

void skip_quote(char type) {
    int prev, current;

    prev = type;
    current = '\0';
    while ((prev == '\\' || current != type) && prev != current) {
        prev = current;
        current = getch();
    }
}

void skip_comment(char c) {
    int prev;

    prev = '\0';
    if (c == '/')
        skip_line();
    else if (c == '*')
        while (prev != '*' && (c = getch()) != '/')
            prev = c;
}

void skip_line(void) {
    while (getch() != '\n')
        ;
}

int cstack[STACKMAX];
int sp = 0;

int getch(void) {
    return (sp > 0) ? cstack[--sp] : getchar();
}

void ungetch(int c) {
    if (sp < STACKMAX)
        cstack[sp++] = c;
    else
        printf("error: stack is full\n");
}
```

**This is the header getword.h header file**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int getword(char *, int);
```

Why am I getting a segmentation fault here?

Comment: I wonder why my question was downvoted. Is this type of question not appropriate on stackoverflow?

Comment: Discussed at MSO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331796/is-this-newbie-question-about-a-segmentation-fault-in-c-not-acceptable-for-stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by using a value of an uninitialized variable having automatic storage duration `root`, which is indeterminate, in the `main()` function. Try initializing it before use, like:

```
struct tnode *root = NULL;
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks! Do you know why it wasn't causing a segmentation fault when the ``MAXWORD`` limit was 169 or higher?

Comment: It was undefined behaviour as well as you have used uninitialized pointer in all paths of execution of your code.

Comment: @MariusPop Anything can happen when *undefined behavior* is invoked. It seems beause you were unlucky enough not to find the issue.

Comment: @MariusPop *Do you know why it wasn't causing a segmentation fault when the MAXWORD limit was 169 or higher?*  Most likely the larger size of `char word[MAXWORD];` array pushes the `root` variable into memory that hasn't been used yet by the pre-`main()` startup code and is thus still all zeros, which is a `NULL` pointer value.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I started to think that my question about undefined behavior doesn't make any sense. But your response helps a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your function

```
struct tnode *addtree(struct tnode *p, char *word) {
    int cond;

    if (p == NULL) {
```

you are using value of pointer `p`, but you pass unitialized pointer to it in main function:

```
root = addtree(root, word);
```

SOLUTION:

Initialize pointer:

```
struct tnode *root = NULL;
```

---

You said

> I get a segmentation fault but only when I set MAXWORD less than 169.

and you ask

> Do you know why it wasn't causing a segmentation fault when the
>   MAXWORD limit was 169 or higher?

The undefined behaviour happened independently of value of `MAXWORD` as you have used uninitialized pointer in all paths of execution of your code. It was undefined behaviour, so undefined behaviour is the answer to your question.

Comment: It feels difficult to accept that there is such a thing as an "undefined behavior" but I guess I have to get used to that. It is what it is. Thanks for the details!